# How to get sum of @ElementCollection with Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, jakarta-ee, jpql

I have a Entity table with following:

@Entity
public class Post {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@NotBlank
@Size(min = 1, max = 2014)
private String text;

@NotNull
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date created;

@NotNull
@ManyToOne
private User author;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<String> votesFor;

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<String> againstFor;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private List<Comment> comments;

public Post() {
    votesFor = new HashSet<>();
    againstFor = new HashSet<>();
    comments = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

I want to make a TypedQuery where i can get the most voted post.
Im adding a vote in the @ElementCollection by following code below.

How do i sum the @ElementCollection and then return a list with posts with the highest votesFor at start and stop with the less votesFor ?

```
public void votesFor(String userId, long postId) {

    Post post = em.find(Post.class, postId);
    if(post == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Post not exists: " + postId);
    }

    if(post.getVotesFor().contains(userId)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("User " + userId + " have already voted");
    }

    post.getVotesFor().add(userId);
    post.getAgainstFor().remove(userId);
}
```

Comment: Not clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JPQL you can use function called SIZE to get ElementCollection size.

I quite don't understand how exactly you want to query your data, so I will give you two different examples of possible usages in your example entity structure.

### Get N most voted posts

To get N most voted post we would need to

1. Sort our posts by size of **votesFor** collection.
2. Limit it by N.

Just like that :

```
select p from Post p order by SIZE(p.votesFor) desc limit :n
```

where **:n** is some parameter in your query

### Get posts with at least N votesFor

Second possible way is to query posts with at least some number of 'votesFor'. To do that you would only need to use WHERE expression, just like that :

```
select p from Post p where SIZE(p.votesFor) >= :n
```

where :n is number of minimal votesFor you are looking for.

More on special operators like SIZE [HERE](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL#JPQL_special_operators)

Comment: Thanx! Its helped me a lot :)

Comment: No problem, happy coding : )